# For any module with vector set $V$ and scalar set $C$, must there exist a set $X$ such that $V$ and $(X → C)$ are isomorphic?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, homotopy-type-theory

Here's some evidence that suggests the affirmative to my question. There exists an isomorphism between:

> $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $(\mathbb{N}^{<n} \to \mathbb{R}$)

> $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ and ($\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$)

> $C$ and $( \to C)$, where $C$ is an underlying set for a ring and  is a singleton set.

If the answer to my question is 'yes', then with the univalence axiom, I can reformulate the definition of a module to be a ring paired with some other set.

Comment: Yes, all three pairs of things you are considering are equivalent types. Your main question can be shown in HoTT for finite dimensional vector spaces. See https://unimath.github.io/agda-unimath/linear-algebra.vectors.html

For infinite dimensional vector spaces, I believe you need the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For finite dimensional vector spaces (over fields), @IsAdisplayName has given the correct answer in the comments. Indeed, if $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space, then it is isomorphic to some $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or $k^n$) and hence isomorphic to a function space by the first example you gave.

For infinite dimensional vector spaces, the answer is in general "no", even if the axiom of choice available. For instance, the $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ of polynomials cannot be isomorphic to a space of the form $(X \to \mathbb{Q})$: If $X$ is finite, then $(X \to \mathbb{Q})$ is, unlike $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, finite dimensional. If $X$ is infinite, then its underlying set is, unlike the underlying set of $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, uncountable.

Over general rings, there are even more counterexamples.

For instance, the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}/(2)$ is not isomorphic to a module of the form $(X \to \mathbb{Z})$: In none of these modules, with the exception of $X = \emptyset$, do we have that $2v = 0$ for all vectors $v$.

Comment: Your second counterexample sufficiently answers my question. However, the first counterexample is questionable to me. $\mathbb{Q}_{n}[X]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}^{n+1}$, which means it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}^{\le n} \to \mathbb{Q}$. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: And if $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ is infinite dimensional, then ought it be isomorphic to $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: You are right about $\mathbb{Q}_n[X]$, but I was referring to $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, the vector space of all polynomials (not only those of degree $\leq n$). And yes, $(\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Q})$ comes close, but this vector space is actually isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[[X]]$, the vector space of formal power series. The difference is that coefficients of polynomials eventually need to be zero, while a formal power series can have arbitrarily many nonzero coefficients.